# Return variables to original values in PCA - R

Tags: r, pca

I can apply PCA to the iris dataset and plot components 1 and 2 to see how the transformation separates the species.

```
library(tidyverse)

x <- iris[,1:4] %>% as.matrix()
pca <- prcomp(x, scale. = TRUE)
summary(pca)

as.data.frame(pca$x) %>% 
  mutate(Species = iris$Species) %>%
  ggplot(aes(PC1,PC2, color = Species)) +
  geom_point()
```

My problem is, since `prcomp` function scaled the values, how can I return them to the original values for the plot? As you can see, the scales go from negative to positive, but the sizes are not negative.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: The whole point of PCA is to transform the original data values (in this case 4 different measurements) by rotating the 4 dimensional plot of points so that the first PC is oriented in the direction of the maximum covariance of the points. The second PC is the next greatest covariance that is orthogonal to the first, etc. The new space shows relationships between the points, but the original coordinate system is lost since PC1 is not one of your columns but a linear combination of all of them.

Comment: dcarlson is correct, but to answer the question how to go back from PCA to original values, you could run the following: `y <- as.data.frame(t(tcrossprod(pca$rotation, pca$x)));
y[] <- mapply(`*`, y, pca$scale);
y[] <- mapply(`+`, y, pca$center)`. You can check this is correct by testing `all.equal(y, iris[, 1:4])`.

Comment: I think this should help https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/229092/how-to-reverse-pca-and-reconstruct-original-variables-from-several-principal-com

Comment: hello @dcarlson, Thank you for the great explanation, I thought unscaled principal components were measures in centimeters, but it seems that I was wrong.

Comment: hello @teunbrand, thank you for the answer, I wrongly believed that the plot axis should be in centimeters, but the new dimensions are relationships between points according to the explanation.